# MAC OS import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql

when i do

import mysql.connector

it says am00.py", line 5, in 
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

but I installed all things that I need(MySQL, python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python)

I checked it by 
`$python3 -m pip freeze`

And I can check

```
mysql==0.0.2
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.19
mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2
mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

What is the problem?!

Comment: Hi, show us how you imported?

Comment: Where is the module installed? Perhaps that location isn't included in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: What command did you use to install?  `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of python. Run both python -m pip install mysql and python3 -m pip install mysql to check

Comment: Where is the module installed? Perhaps that location isn't included in your PYTHONPATH –  How can I check and change it to include my location?? @Gerard

Comment: I run both now but it doesn't work @CanciuCostin

Comment: @SamimHakimi 
import mysql.connector
 like this

Comment: When I do "import mysql.connector' in python shell it doesn't make problems

Comment: Oh guys! import mysql.connector WORKS NOW! THANKS SO MUCH
But other modules like sklearn, numpy pandas still don't work 

What does the python -m pip install mean? @CanciuCostin